# scraping specific data from html using BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to get the best search result position of few product in the below link

https://www.purplle.com/search?q=hair%20fall%20shamboo

I used below tools to get the html details from the page
++

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.purplle.com/search?q=hair%20fall%20shamboo")
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
driver.quit()
```

++

now I am confused how to get the product names and position(to get the best rank in the search )from this html.

I used the below method to get the details of the products but the output has a lot of unwanted things too.

details = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'pr'})

any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you meant by position. However, the below script can fetch you the title of different products and its position (allegedly) from that page:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.purplle.com/search?q=hair%20fall%20shamboo")

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
for item in soup.find_all(class_="prd-lstng pr"):
    name = item.find_all(class_="pro-name el2")[0].text
    position = item.find_all(class_="mrl5 tx-std30")[0].text
    print(name,position)

driver.quit()
```

Comment: A shopper typically searches for products from https://www.purplle.com/ say he is searching for ‘hair fall shampoo’ in purplle.com
The search results contain different products from various brands like Tresemme, Loreal and Dove. I am trying to get the best rank for these brands.  


for eg in https://www.purplle.com/search?q=hair%20fall%20shamboo good vibes has rank 1 Michel Mercier has rank 2 and Livon Serum has rank 3

Comment: I don't see a single variation when I look at the results and the ones in that webpage. However, the webpage displays it's full content if it is made to scroll downward until you reach the bottom. Maybe the product names you are talking about are in the last portion or somewhere in the page that is not visible from my end if i do not scroll. Your requirement was to learn the looping to parse the products from that page not to handle the lazyload.

Comment: the actual search key word was "hair fall shampoo" and the url becomes

Comment: url becomes "https://www.purplle.com/search?q=hair%20fall%20shampoo"  seems the driver is not downloading the data from the whole page, is it possible to get the first 100 elements in "load more option"? Also when I inspect the element I noticed "item_position" parameter is showing the product items position based on the search. can we extract that too?

Comment: Follow this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48040836/my-scraper-fails-to-get-all-the-items-from-a-webpage) to get your additional requirement satisfied. There is an exact same webpage with somewhat similar problem in the thread.