# My scraper fails to get all the items from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written some code in python in combination with selenium to parse different product names from a webpage. There are few load more buttons visible if the browser is made to scroll downward. The webpage displays it's full content if the page is made to scroll downmost until there is no load more button to click. My scraper seems to be doing good but I'm not getting all the results. There are around 200 products in that page but I'm getting 90 out of them. What change should I bring about in my scraper to get them all? Thanks in advance.

The webpage I'm dealing with: [Page_Link](https://www.purplle.com/search?q=hair%20fall%20shamboo)

This is the script I'm trying with:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("put_above_url_here")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

page = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".listing_item")))
for scroll in range(17):
    page.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        load = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".lm-btm")
        load.click()
    except Exception:
        pass

for item in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[id^=item_]"))):
    name = item.find_element_by_css_selector(".pro-name.el2").text
    print(name)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code to get required data:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.purplle.com/search?q=hair%20fall%20shamboo")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

header = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("header")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display='none';", header)

while True:

    try:
        page = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".listing_item")))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", page)
        page.send_keys(Keys.END)
        load = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "LOAD MORE")))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", load)
        load.click()
        wait.until(EC.staleness_of(load))
    except:
        break

for item in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[id^=item_]"))):
    name = item.find_element_by_css_selector(".pro-name.el2").text
    print(name)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Why are you so damn accurate all the times @ sir Andersson? It perfectly did the job. FYI, recently I've learnt something which you may like. Whenever there is an option for `scrollIntoView`, you can just achieve that using `page.location` or `load.location` instead of `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", page)` or the latter. One thing to know sir:  I could not understand the `header` part. Was it necessary? Thanks for everything and once again a single like is not enough for your answer.

Comment: I know that `location_once_scrolled_into_view` intend to scroll page, but it doesn't seem to work anymore... Maybe now `location` property should do the same. I will try it. Thanks. As for *header*: the header of page is fixed, so when you scroll page down to "LOAD MORE" button - it's not visible as it covered by header, so you cannot click it. It's little hack to avoid using scroll with offset...

Comment: One last thing to know sir: should I always use this way `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display='none';", header)` whenever it is necessary to set a `header` as landmark, i meant this `"arguments[0].style.display='none';"` portion?

Comment: This is the way to make element *invisible*. If you don't want to make header completelly invisible, there should also be the way to change property `position` of header from `"fixed"` to `"absolute"`

Comment: No sir, this is absolutely alright. I just wanted to learn a bit more that is why I asked such silly question.

Answer (score 0):

You should only Use Selenium as a last resort.

A simple look around in the webpage showed the API it called to get your data.

It returns a JSON output with all the details:

[Link](https://www.purplle.com/api/shop/itemsv2?list_type=search&custom=&list_type_value=hair%20fall%20shamboo&page=2&sort_by=rel)

You can now just loop over and store in a dataframe easily.

Very fast, fewer errors than selenium.

Comment: Thanks Darshan Jadav, for you suggestion. I'm not after the data actually; rather, i wanted  to reach the full content smashing the barrier programmatically.

Comment: Just curious... how did you find this? I'm using Chrome and used the Network tab to see the traffic and see that there is an XHR request in the form that you posted above. Is that how you found it? If there is more than on XHR request, how do you find the right one? Are you just opening them one at a time until you find the right one? Thanks.

Comment: You can find that in network > xhr. After reloading the page when you hover your mouse over those links in the left sided bar generated by xhr, you can see few links which are more or less similar to the one you are playing with @JeffC. Click on those to find the right one. That's it. Here is one such: [Json_link](https://www.purplle.com/api/shop/itemsv2?list_type=search&custom=&list_type_value=hair%20fall%20shamboo&page=1&sort_by=rel)

Comment: I would like to add to Topto's comment, It is done that way. But sometimes you would have to replicate the Request Headers for that request, If there are more; there is a 'preview' tab just in that window, click that and it will show the data fetched. Thanks